# Can't get a new window to be created in a google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a button located on my popup.html page to create another window on the browser with a button click. When I click the button however nothing happened. I think I have the eventPage set up incorrectly. So to recap I would like a butotn on my popup.html page to create a new window with a pre-existing html page called tabby.html

POPUP.HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="button tabby" id="create_button">Create Tab</div>
</body> 

</html>
```

eventPage.js

```
function create() {
        var createPage = {
            "url": "tabby.html"
            , "type": "popup"
            , "top": 5
            , "left": 5
            , "width": screen.availWidth
            , "height": screen.availHeight
        };
        chrome.windows.create(createPage, function () {});
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    $("#create_button").addEventListener('onclick', create);
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "name"
    , "version": "0.0.1"
    , "manifest_version": 2
    , "description": "DESC"
    , "icons": {
        "128": "img/icon128.png"
        , "48": "img/icon48.png"
        , "16": "img/icon16.png"
    }
    , "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icon48.png"
        , "default_title": "name"
        , "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
    , "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js"]
        , "persistance": false
    }
    , "web_accessible_resources": ["tabby.html"]
    , "permissions": [
          "http://*/*"
    , "https://*/*"
        , "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: See the extension overview documentation: the event page is a separate page (an invisible window), not related to the popup window/page. Move the popup code in the popup script (script.js). Also start using devtools debugger: rightclick the popup, then Inspect. In devtools you'll see the document and scripts of the page, which you can debug, run, step-through, and inspect.

Comment: Ok I'l try that!

Comment: Oh thanks so the event page shouldn't be connected to anything in the popup.html page?

Comment: It's a different *page* that's needed for a totally different purpose. See the documentation.